# Why I get an empty response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm trying to get all column names from a table:

```
$query = "SHOW columns FROM table;";
$json = array();
if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 
        array_push($json, $row['Field']);
    }
}

header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
//print_r($json);
 echo json_encode($json);
 exit;
```

The jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data : {
        q : "abc"
    },
    success : function(data) {
        if(data.length!=0){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            $("#content").append(data);
        }
        else{
            $("#content").text("no data");
        }
    },
    error : function(data) {
        console.error("error: " + data));
    }
});
```

When I use `print_r($json)` I get this response, which is correct:

```
"Array\n(\n    [0] => ID\n    [1] => Name\n    [2] => Age\n    [3] => Gender\n   )\n"
```

But when I use `json_encode($json)` I get `no data`, so the response is empty.

**Update**

Ok, I uncommented `dataType: "json"`, added `header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );` and edited the `error callback` as suggested.

This is the error message I get:

```
parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
Stack-Trace:
m.parseJSON@http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js:4:15732
Pc@http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js:4:18120
x@http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js:4:21525
.send/b@http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js:4:25897
```

Comment: Put `console.log(data);` in the `success()` function and see what it yields (**before** the if statement).

Comment: Un-comment the `dataType: "json"` line.

Comment: Also, try to use the `error` callback *correctly*: `error: function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.log(status, error); }`.

Comment: Ok, I have updated it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the correct header type, before echoing the result:

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
echo json_encode( $json);
```

Also, try to set the AJAX request type, to `GET` instead of `POST`:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    data: 'q=abc',
    success : function(data) {
        if(data.length!=0){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            $("#content").append(data);
        }else{
            $("#content").text("no data");
        }
    },
    error : function(data) {
        console.error("error: " + data));
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

If you are using Google Chrome (highly recommended), use the Inspector (Ctrl+Shift+I)'s **Network** tab, **XHR** sub-section, in which you will see attempts for the AJAX request.

Under the **Name** column, click on the request, and on the right side, you may use  **Headers** and **Response** sections to check If the AJAX request is doing fine.